# SSH Tunnel from Remote Server to Remote Server (to connect RStudio to MySQL)

Tags: mysql, r, ssh, rstudio, rstudio-server

I (Local Z) do data analysis on a remote server (Server A), and I need to connect to a database (Database D) on another remote server (Server B).

I can connect to Database D by SSH tunneling to Server B from Local Z.

However, I run RStudio Server on Server A, and I need to connect to Database D within RStudio on Server A.

How can I go about SSH tunneling from Server A to Server B and connecting to MySQL within RStudio?

EDIT:
I'm using the RMySQL package to connect to the database within RStudio. Database D also only allows local connections, so SSH tunnel is required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved: after SSH tunneling from my server to the 2nd server, for some reason (if anyone knows, please add a comment), changing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' in the R code allowed me to connect (contrary to settings I've used in similar ways for other databases...).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with proxy socket :

`root@serverA:~# ssh root@serverB -D 1337`

It'll tell ssh on serverA to listening on the `localhost:1337`, change the port `1337` to use the one of the database (like the distant) and it should be "remotely at home"...